# Error: while fetch from Shopify: Network error: Unexpected end of JSON input at new ApolloError

Tags: next.js, graphql, shopify, apollo

I'm working on a project in Next.js where I want to take data from my Shopify store using Apollo Client.
I set up my Apollo Client:

```
function createApolloClient(initialState = {}) {
 const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";
 return new ApolloClient({
   connectToDevTools: isBrowser,
   ssrMode: !isBrowser, 
   link: new HttpLink({
     uri: `${process.env.shopifyURL}/admin/api/2022-04/graphql.json`,
     xcredentials: "include", 
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": `${process.env.storefrontKey}`,
       "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
     },
     fetchOptions: {
       mode: "no-cors",
     },
     fetch: !isBrowser && fetch,
   }),
   cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState),
 });
}
```

Then I made my query:

```
const QUERY = gql`
    {
      query
      getProducts {
        products(first: 50) {
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              legacyResourceId
              title
            }
          }
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            endCursor
            startCursor
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
```

Lastly, in my component, I use the useQuery in this way:

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(QUERY);
  if (error) console.log(error);
  if (loading || !data) console.log(loading);
  console.log(data);
```

My problem is that data is always undefined and in the console I get this error:

> Error: Network error: Unexpected end of JSON input
> at new ApolloError

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpmWP.png)

Comment: remove query keyword from the code

Comment: I faced this issue today. Saw their changelog that they fixed it recently for node API. https://www.linkedin.com/posts/s-agrawal_shopify-developer-tips-activity-6942707414903181312-KIJU?utm_source=linkedin_share&utm_medium=member_desktop_web